# Changing MAC address disconnects Wi-Fi

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I am using OpenSUSE 13.2 with kernel **3.16.7-21-desktop x86_64**.

I am trying to change the MAC address of my system by using the following commands:

```
ifconfig | grep HWaddr
ifconfig wlp2s0 down
macchanger -r wlp2s0
ifconfig wlp2s0 up
```

This is changing the MAC address but as soon as the MAC address is changed, it disconnects from my Wireless network. When it connects back to the network, the MAC address reverts back to the original address.

Any ideas how I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: What Linux distribution and version? Is Network Manager active?

Comment: I am using OpenSUSE 13.2. Yes the Network Manager is active.

Comment: Either change the Mac Address using Network Manager's GUI, or disable it and use command-line tools. You can't have both.

Comment: I tried changing it using the "Network Manager" in the "Cloned Address" field. But when I use "ifconfig" command to check the network address, it remains unchanged.

Comment: This question might seem disparaging, but have you tried disconnecting and reconnecting the connection after filling in the *Cloned Address* field?

Comment: After I change the "Cloned Address" field, the connection automatically disconnects from the preferred Wireless network and then does not seem to connect back to it. I even restarted the machine but it was not reconnecting to the network. After I deleted the "Cloned Address" field, i t automatically connected to the network!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have MAC address filtering set up on your access point/wireless router. Try to turn it off or register the spoofed MAC address on the access point/router.

Comment: I don't think that MAC address filtering option is turned on because a number of devices have connected to the network successfully (after giving the password/network key).